# android silent sign in without user interaction with logged in gmail account in account manager

Tags: android, google-signin

i can get details from silent sign in if the user logins from account chooser.
I want to perform operation without account chooser

I am trying to show user profile details like profile image, display from my app without user inputs. By silent sign in iam using silentsign in api.

Is there any way to get signin without account chooser from accountmanager,

```
private void silentSign() {
//        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
//        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
            // There's immediate result available.
            handleSignInResult(pendingResult.get());


        } else {
            // There's no immediate result ready, displays some progress indicator and waits for the
            // async callback.
//            showProgressIndicator();
  pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                    handleSignInResult(result);
//                    hideProgressIndicator();
                }
            });
        }

  private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        //If the login succeed
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //Getting google account
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            //Displaying name and email
            textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
            textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
            textGivenName.setText(acct.getGivenName());
            textFamilyName.setText( acct.getFamilyName());
            textid.setText(acct.getId());
            Uri photoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();



            //Initializing image loader
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                    .getImageLoader();

            imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


            //Loading image

            profilePhoto.setImageURI(photoUrl);

        } else {
            //If login fails
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the catch here is, for the first time when user signs in you have to notify him and take his permission. When the user grants permission, you can save the token into server database. Now the scenario begins, user has uninstalled the app or installed it on a different device where he/she is logged in with the same account, now since you already have taken the permission you can simply show a `toast/snackbar` and greet user with a welcome back message and silently sign him in.

I hope this clarifies.

**PS**. The explanation was long and hence did not put it in the comments.

Comment: i want to show the user gmail profile image, username from the gmail account he logged in the device(by using the account manger we wont be able to get user gmail profile image). these needs to be displayed once the app launches(fyi... without user interactions like gmail account chooser if there are multiple accounts)

Comment: As per requirement, want to show user details like below image in our app:https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidheadlines.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F06%2FYouTube-for-Android-TV-New-4.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidheadlines.com%2F2017%2F06%2Fandroid-tv-youtube-gets-a-new-look-with-latest-update.html&docid=YFuQTvqF6A3jnM&tbnid=n1xvchTuiu9vLM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiZtsKiu_nVAhXKo48KHUc_DuEQMwgmKAAwAA..i&w=1366&h=768&safe=off&client=firefox-b-ab&bih=681&biw=1467&q=youtube%20android%20user%20profile&ved=0ahUKEwiZtsKiu_nVAhXKo48KHUc_DuEQMwgmKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: So as I said, u have to ask first time for permission and then save the token. After that next time u can use this token and fetch using REST API or SDK then after

Comment: can you share an example

Comment: No mate, u have to try on ur own and seek community's help if u stuck somewhere.

Comment: got the desired result using oauth instead of gmail sign in and silent sign in apis:https://bhargavaroyal.wordpress.com/2017/08/30/fetch-and-read-user-profile-details-using-oauth-from-gmail-api-android/